# Nhibernate multiple component properties of the same type in a class

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, properties, components

I have a class LINE which contains two properties of type POINT.
I would like POINT to be a component property. 
If LINE were to contain only 1 POINT, this would be no problem, but since it contains 2 POINTs I would think I needed to distinguish them (so a prefix or suffix can be applied to column names).
I tried using the PropertyName attribute of the ComponentProperty tag, but still only one set of X and Y columns is generated inside my LINE table.

For clarity, my goal is to have a LINE table with a Point1_X, Point1_Y, Point2_X and a Point2_Y column.

I use Nhibernate.Mapping.Attributes, below you can see my mapping

```
[Class]
public class Line : EntityBase
{
  [ComponentProperty(PropertyName = "Point1")]
  public UiPoint Point1 { get; set; }

  [ComponentProperty(PropertyName = "Point2")]
  public UiPoint Point2 { get; set; }

  //omitted the constructor
```

}

```
[Component]
public class UiPoint
{
  [Property]
  public double X { get; set; }

  [Property]
  public double Y { get; set; }

  //omitted the constructor 
}
```

In the meanwhile I figured out the following XML mapping wil solve my problem

```
<class name="Domain.WashProcessLine,Domain">
    <id name="Id" />
    <component name="Point1">
       <property name="X" type="Double" column="Point1_X" />
       <property name="Y" type="Double" column="Point1_Y" />
    </component>
    <component name="Point2">
        <property name="X" type="Double" column="Point2_X" />
        <property name="Y" type="Double" column="Point2_Y" />
    </component>
</class>
```

found an option on https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/components.html

the following tagging creates the desired table structure, but does give me a casting exception (from UiPoint to IDictionary) when retreiving the property from the database.

So I'm not entirely there yet :(

```
[Class]
public class Line : EntityBase
{
    [DynamicComponent(1)]               
    [Property(2, Name = "X", Column = "Point1_X", TypeType = typeof(double))]
    [Property(3, Name = "Y", Column = "Point1_Y", TypeType = typeof(double))]
    public UiPoint Point1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [DynamicComponent(1)]               
    [Property(2, Name = "X", Column = "Point2_X", TypeType = typeof(double))]
    [Property(3, Name = "Y", Column = "Point2_Y",TypeType=typeof(double))]
    public UiPoint Point2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the unit tests for Nhibernate.Mapping.Attributes, and trying a number of different solutions, we found that the cleanest way (unfortunately) to fix the situation provided above, was by injecting some raw xml into our mapping. This means we removed the property attributes in our line class and replaced them with a single entry as shown below

```
[RawXml(After=typeof(ComponentAttribute), Content = @"<component name=""Point1"">
<property name=""X"" type=""Double"" column=""Point1_X"" />
   <property name=""Y"" type=""Double"" column=""Point1_Y"" />
</component>
<component name=""Point2"">
    <property name=""X"" type=""Double"" column=""Point2_X"" />
    <property name=""Y"" type=""Double"" column=""Point2_Y"" />
</component>")]
```

Answer (score 0):

This question and answer helped me out while playing around with [NHibernatePets Sample](http://www.fincher.org/tips/Languages/NHibernate.shtml)

I thought I'd have a go at including the above Line/Point implementation. My code is below if anyone is interested. I found some frustrating quirks with using Attributes too. The first being that if you are using multiple classes with [Id] declarations such as:

```
    [Id(Name = "id")]
    [Generator(1, Class = "native")]
```

then you need to specify the order number (1) for the Generator or else the generated mapping may omit the Generator attribute for one or more of your classes. Apparently this has something to do with the way VS handles things.

Another thing I found when comparing the sample Pet.hbm.xml file with the generated file output using:

`//Export to a mapping file when required. Test/Production.
                HbmSerializer.Default.Serialize(typeof(Pet).Assembly,"Pets.hbm.xml");`

was that the Access="field" property shouldn't be set in the [Id] attribute, even though it was in the sample mapping file.

Line and UiPoint Classes (in NHibernatePets namespace)...

```
[Class(Lazy = true)]
public class Line
{

    [Id(Name = "id")]
    [Generator(1, Class = "native")]
    #if useAttributes
        virtual public int id { get; set; }
    #else
        private int id;
    #endif

    const string point1 =
    @"<component name= ""Point1"" class= ""NHibernatePets.UiPoint"" >
        <property name=""X"" 
              type=""Double"" 
              column=""Point1_X""/> 
        <property name=""Y"" 
              type=""Double"" 
              column=""Point1_Y""/>
      </component>";

    const string point2 =
    @"<component name=""Point2"" class=""NHibernatePets.UiPoint"" >
          <property name=""X""
              type=""Double""
              column=""Point2_X""/>
          <property name=""Y""
              type=""Double""
              column=""Point2_Y""/>
      </component>";

    [RawXml(After = typeof(ComponentAttribute), Content = point1)]
    virtual public UiPoint Point1 { get; set; }

    [RawXml(After = typeof(ComponentAttribute), Content = point2)]
    virtual public UiPoint Point2 { get; set; }

}

//Don't need any Attributes set on this class as it's defined in the RawXml.
public class UiPoint
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}
```

In Main()...

```
        //Create the Line record
        Line newLine = new Line
        {
            Point1 = new UiPoint { X = 100.1, Y = 100.2 },
            Point2 = new UiPoint { X = 200.1, Y = 200.2 }
        };
        try
        {
            using (ISession session = OpenSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    session.Save(newLine);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Saved NewLine to the database");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { Console.WriteLine(e); }
```

In Public Class Program...

```
    static ISessionFactory SessionFactory;
    static ISession OpenSession()
    {

        if (SessionFactory == null) //not threadsafe
        { //SessionFactories are expensive, create only once
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

            #if useAttributes
            {
                configuration.SetDefaultAssembly("NHibernatePets");
                //configuration.SetDefaultAssembly(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ToString());
                //To use Components and other structures, AssemblyName must be set.
                //configuration.SetDefaultAssembly(typeof(Pet).Assembly.ToString());
                configuration.AddInputStream(NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.HbmSerializer.Default.Serialize(typeof(Pet).Assembly));
            }
            #else
                configuration.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
            #endif

            //Export to a mapping file when required. Test/Production.
            HbmSerializer.Default.Serialize(typeof(Pet).Assembly,"Pets.hbm.xml");

            SessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
        }
        return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
```